# Is there a way to move back a line after using fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

Is there a way to move back the line just read after calling `fgets`? I know when you use `fgetc` you can do `ungetc`. Is there a way I can do something similar for `fgets`?

The reason I am asking this is because I have an `fgets` in an if statment and I dont want the `fgets` to be actually executed I just want to know whether it is going to return a `NULL` or not. But I know that if the `fgets` is within an if statement it will be executed. This is why I want to know how can I move it back to the point in the file before `fgets` was called.

Comment: `fseek()` can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fungets.

You *can* save a position in an input stream using `ftell`, and reposition to that point using `fseek`.  It is useful for files, but not reading from the terminal (i.e., the standard input).

Further reading

- [fgetpos, fseek, fsetpos, ftell, rewind - reposition a stream](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek)
- [12.18 File Positioning](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html) (The GNU C Library)

Comment: It'd be a great function name anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use ftell and store the position. With fseek you set it whenever needed.

You could search for a newline or start of file though, but saving the position is easier to code.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. The POSIX standard guarantees only one byte of push-back.

It's not clear why you want to do this but if you're trying to check whether you've reached the end of the file, the correct thing is to test the result of `fgetc` for equality with `EOF` (and then doing `ungetc`). It's not sufficient to call `feof` on the stream because the end-of-file bit is set only once a read operation fails to read any more bytes.

```
int c = ungetc(fgetc(f), f); // peek one byte
if (c == EOF) {
    ...
}
```